# Trying to understand random dynamical systems

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $\{\theta_t : \Omega \mapsto \Omega \  | \  t \in T \}$ be a family of measure preserving transformations on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}).$  A *measurable random dynamical system* on the measurable space $(X, \mathcal{B})$ over $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \theta_T)$ is a mapping

$$\phi : T \times \Omega \times X \mapsto X$$
so that the mappings $\phi(t,\omega, \cdot) : X \mapsto X$ form a cocyle over $\theta(\cdot)$.

I admit it: this is over my head.

I think I understand the basic idea of a random dynamical systems. We take some point $x_0$, and map it some other point. But, the maps are random so each map is different, hence the word "random" in "random dynamical system."  (is this correct?)

However, I am not seeing that in this definition. I was wondering if someone could explain this in somewhat less rigorous manner, even if the itty gritty details are missed.

So, if someone could provide a pretty detailed explanation of this definition, with less rigor, and maybe an example, that would be great!

Edit: There is a question similar to this but the answer did not help.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain what is missing in my answer.

Comment: @JohnB It is wonderful. I just cannot see that in this definition for some reason.

Comment: I see. The extra element is $\Omega$, right? By taking different $\omega$'s you select different maps. You just need to think that $\omega\mapsto\phi(t,\omega,\cdot)$ is a measurable map that has associated a probability measure. When we say "random" we are referring to this measure, nothing else. For example, if you consider a delta measure, then "random" becomes "deterministic".

Comment: Is there a book or something you found this definition in? It'll be helpful to mention it.